# why shell for expression cannot parse xargs parameter correctly

Tags: shell, for-loop, xargs

I have a black list to save tag id list, e.g. `1-3,7-9`, actually it represents `1,2,3,7,8,9`. And  could expand it by below shell

```
for i in {1..3,7..9}; do for j in {$i}; do echo -n "$j,"; done; done
1,2,3,7,8,9
```

but first I should convert `-` to `..`

```
echo -n "1-3,7-9" | sed 's/-/../g'
1..3,7..9
```

then put it into `for` expression as a parameter

```
echo -n "1-3,7-9" | sed 's/-/../g'  | xargs -I @ for i in {@}; do for j in {$i}; do echo -n "$j,"; done; done
zsh: parse error near `do'

echo -n "1-3,7-9" | sed 's/-/../g'  | xargs -I @ echo @
1..3,7..9
```

but `for` expression cannot parse it correctly, why is so?

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't do anything to stop the outermost shell from picking up the special keywords and characters ( `do`, `for`, `$`, etc ) that you mean to be run by `xargs`.

`xargs` isn't a shell built-in; it gets the command line you want it to run for each element on stdin, from its *arguments*.  just like any other program, if you want `;` or any other sequence special to be bash in an argument, you need to somehow escape it.

It seems like what you really want here, in my mind, is to invoke in a subshell a command ( your nested `for` loops ) for each input element.

I've come up with this; it seems to to the job:

```
echo -n "1-3,7-9" \
| sed 's/-/../g'  \
| xargs -I @  \
bash -c "for i in {@}; do for j in {\$i}; do echo -n \"\$j,\"; done; done;"
```

which gives:

```
{1..3},{7..9},
```

Comment: Thanks! but actually I want is convert `1-3,7-9` to `1,2,3,7,8,9`

Answer (score 0):

Could use below shell to achieve this

```
# Mac newline need special treatment
echo "1-3,7-9" | sed -e 's/-/../g' -e $'s/,/\\\n/g' | xargs -I@ echo 'for i in {@}; do echo -n "$i,"; done' | bash
1,2,3,7,8,9,%


#Linux
echo "1-3,7-9" | sed -e 's/-/../g' -e 's/,/\n/g' | xargs -I@ echo 'for i in {@}; do echo -n "$i,"; done' | bash
1,2,3,7,8,9,
```

but use this way is a little complicated maybe `awk` is more intuitive

```
# awk
echo "1-3,7-9,11,13-17" | awk '{n=split($0,a,","); for(i=1;i<=n;i++){m=split(a[i],a2,"-");for(j=a2[1];j<=a2[m];j++){print j}}}' | tr '\n' ','
1,2,3,7,8,9,11,13,14,15,16,17,%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -n "1-3,7-9" | perl -ne 's/-/../g;$,=",";print eval $_'
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.